# Inside admin when i click on system i'm throwing an error on m2 2.2.5

Tags: module, cron, system-config, group

I've tried to change the ID name but it did not work.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Element with id "system_cron_template_use_separate_process" already exists

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Element with id "system_cron_template_use_separate_process" already exists
#0 /chroot/home/this/my.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php(93): Magento\Framework\Data\Form->checkElementId('system_cron_tem...')
#1 /chroot/home/this/my.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/AbstractForm.php(157): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->addElement(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Select), false)
#2 /chroot/home/this/my.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Fieldset.php(212): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm->addField('system_cron_tem...', 'select', Array, false)
#3 /chroot/home/this/my.com/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php(392): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->addField('system_cron_tem...', 'select', Array)
```

I tried changing the ID here: vendor/magento/module-cron/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

It did work.

Answer (score 2):

first run command `grep -ir "system_cron_template_use_separate_process" app/` to find out the duplicate element id

Second, then change it and then run command -

`rm -rf var/cache* generated/*`

then check again.

Comment: The first command grep -ir "system_cron_template_use_separate_process" app/ didn't return anything. @Shashank

Comment: ok so you are getting this error when you go to `system > configuration`. correct ?

Comment: also please mention which magento version are you using ?

Comment: Correct, inside admin when I click on Configuration > Advanced > System

Comment: 2.2.5 is the version i'm running.

Comment: ok, can you please run same command for `vendo/magentor` folder i.e. `grep -ir "system_cron_template_use_separate_process" vendor/magento`

Comment: it came back with no results either.... =/

Comment: I will try it myself get back to you

Comment: Anything else i may try?

Comment: @getData, can you please try to run below commands one by one-
`grep -ir "use_separate_process" vendor/magento/*` and `grep -ir "use_separate_process" app/*`  and share the result from both commands.

Comment: @getData, have you fixed this issue ?